# Basic Apply in R dataframe (possible for loops as well)

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm trying to do some work on a basic dataframe, you can see it below:

```
> print(thisEmailList)
          user_name            user_email
1         Test, Joe    joejoejt@gmeel.com
2 adminintor, Admin jimmyadminj@gmeel.com
```

I would like to send some emails to these folks, but I am unsure what is the best approach. I have a function, sendmail, that seems to work fine with strings, but how do I iterate or apply this function to my dataframe?
I've tried many different tacts, for loops, and functions in lapply, but I cannot seem to get it to appear in the same way the database puts it out. I always seem get something to this effect:

```
          user_name
1         Test, Joe
2 adminintor, Admin
             user_email
1    joejoejt@gmeel.com
2 jimmyadminj@gmeel.com
```

I am thinking of thisEmailList as rows and columns, and I would like to loop through the rows, not the columns. R has been quite the difference in how to think, and I am just not getting the syntax, or how I go about sending an email to *each row* in the above.

### Update 1

I think I finally figured it out, for a forloop anyway. If anyone has a suggestion that doesn't involved a for loop, that would be fantastic.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(thisEmailList)){
    #Note this is just for testing, the sendmailr part has never been an issue, just getting the row/columns to loop in the right order.
    print(paste(thisEmailList[i,2], thisEmailList[i,1]))
}
[1] "joejoejt@gmeel.com Test, Joe"
[1] "jimmyadminj@gmeel.com adminintor, Admin"
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to send one email with a particular choice of name and email and we can show you how to automate that.

Comment: Your solution works, but you should generally try to avoid looping in `R` unless you have no other choice.

Comment: ^ Not necessarily true.  You should do what is most efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the basic `apply` function in row-mode (second parameter is 1):

```
apply(data.frame(thisEmailList$user_name, thisEmailList$user_email),
      1,
      function(x) {
          # send email to user x[1]
          # whose email address is x[2] )
      })
```

You can't use the normal data frame column references inside `apply`, so I create a temporary input data frame whose first column (`x[1]`) is the `user_name` and whose second column (`x[2]`) is the `user_email`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, Ive put in just a simple print(x$user_email) statement, and I get the following error back: Error in x$user_email : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @TimothyHarding I cleaned up my code please have a look.  Great first name, by the way ^ ^

Comment: Thanks Tim! you too!, I gave this a shot (skipping the sendmailr part for now) print(paste0(x[1],x[2])) and it prints out what you'd expect: [1] "Test, Joejoejoejt@gmeel.com"
[1] "adminintor, Adminjimmyadminj@gmeel.com"
[1] "Test, Joejoejoejt@gmeel.com" "adminintor, Adminjimmyadminj@gmeel.com", but then it adds that third line with all the values again, I'm confused by the third line.

Comment: The output you are seeing in the last line is just an artifact of the `R` console.  I checked the `apply` function and it is indeed only iterating once over each row in the data frame.  So you can just ignore this last line.

Comment: You may as well just use a matrix because apply is going to change that data frame into a matrix anyway